# Can I swap Alt+Tab for Alt+Esc in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hotkeys

I quite like that you can use Alt+Esc to cycle trough applications instantly, but I'm so used to typing Alt+Tab, is it possible to make it behave like Alt+Esc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an open source software as [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).
In the [Remap section](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Remap.htm) you can find many examples.
More specifically you can see how to remap [each single tab](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Remap.htm).
Give a look to the [full table of keys](http://ahkscript.org/docs/KeyList.htm). It can work something similar to

```
Alt & Tab::Control & Esc
```

**References:**

1. [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) site.
2. [Remap](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Remap.htm) section of the documentation.
3. [Hotkeys](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#AltTabDetail) section of the documentation.
4. The full [keylist](http://ahkscript.org/docs/KeyList.htm).