# win 10 autohotkey; how do you remap window swapping from alt-tab to ctrl-tab?

Tags: macos, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I recently swapped the ctrl and alt functions on my computer to make it feel more like a mac, but one thing is still bugging me. When I press alt-tab now I cycle through different tabs of the application I'm using, but I want it to cycle through windows, which is what ctrl-tab now does.
Does anyone know of a script I can run to take care of that? Thanks!

EDIT: I still want both the functions, I just want their keys to be swapped (instead of alt-tab swapping windows, I want ctrl-tab to. Instead of ctrl-tab swapping tabs, I want alt-tab to. This is the only function I want swapped)

Comment: ALT+TAB always cycles through all active programs.  You are not going to be able to disable that functionality.

Comment: Disclaimer: I haven't tried this: https://www.howtogeek.com/194811/how-to-prevent-the-windows-key-alttab-and-sticky-keys-from-ruining-your-gaming/

Comment: @Ramhound Not trying to disable it, I'm trying to remap it.

Comment: @wysiwyg You wouldn't happen to know how to swap the keys, would you? That only says how to disable them.

Comment: @Zephyzu just dropping by to say I'm having the same irk, and am wondering if in the intervening 3 years here you've found a good workaround that you can come back and answer this question yourself; I've been given a windows machine for a new client at work and my muscle memory from 8+ years on mac is really frustrating me...

Answer (score 5):

try this

Ctrl & Tab::AltTab

Comment: Why would I want to try this, ie what will happen (or not happen)?

Comment: Amazing, I have been trying countless AutoHotKey recipes, this is the only one that works. And it is so simple! I would give +10 if I could. Thank you.

Comment: works perfectly in win 10! Thank you!! All other solutions either too complex or not working

Answer (score 0):

Make ahk swap 'em keys globally:

```
LAlt::LCtrl 
LCtrl::LAlt
```

Comment: I already did. What I'm trying to do now is swap only the function I mentioned back to it's original position so it better emulates a mac style of keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have said there seem to be a number of ways to possibly do this:

- try some sort of registry hack

  https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/

  https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/
- try some program which can be used to achieve the registry hack. Note, that I'm seeing limitations on many of the programs that I'm seeing out there though

  [Can I swap Alt+Tab for Alt+Esc in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/994800/can-i-swap-alttab-for-altesc-in-windows-10)
- attempt to rewire your keyboard. This is not really a realistic option in many cases (especially if you're dealing with laptops but I've done stuff like this in the past when spare parts were scarce) but I guess if you're desperate enough it's a possibility
- try the following application. It feels like it could do what you want but I haven't tried it (and I don't have a Windows 10 machine handy)

  [How can I restore Ctrl+<key> functionality in Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator?](https://superuser.com/questions/171307/how-can-i-restore-ctrlkey-functionality-in-microsoft-keyboard-layout-creator)

  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121760/remap-keyboard-combinations-not-just-single-registry-values
- another option is to simply write your own program. Honestly, the question worded strangely so it's easy to misinterpret. You want a program/script to remap based on key combination and timing which shouldn't be too hard to make. If you can't do it yourself go to a place where you can hire someone cheaply to get the code done...

  http://www.rent-acoder.com/

  https://www.freelancer.com.au/

  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705163/how-to-capture-combination-key-event

  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg153546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I already got the keys swapped with autohotkey, what I'm trying to do now is swap one function back to it's original keymapping without messing with anything else

Comment: See addition in updated post

Comment: Sorry about the weird wording, I'm by no means good with computers.
Autohotkey uses its own script which you can use to change pretty much any keybinding on your computer if you know it. For instance, I used this script:
LCtrl::Alt
LAlt::Ctrl
to swap everything that control does with alt, so now the alt key acts like control and is in the same place as the command key on a mac, which I'm used to. the only issue I'm facing now is that now alt-tab cycles between tabs of a program and ctrl-tab cycles between open programs. I want alt-tab to cycle open programs and ctrl-tab to cycle tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I borrowed this from somewhere: this will fix not only alt tab, but also alt shift tab.

```
; Remap Ctrl-Tab to Alt-Tab
^Tab::
Send {Alt down}{Tab}
Keywait Control
Send {Alt up}
return

; Remap Ctrl-Shift-Tab to Alt-Shift-Tab
^+Tab::
Send {Alt down}{Shift down}{Tab}
Keywait Control
Send {Alt up}
Send {Shift up}
return
```